# How to integrate a pyglet opengl context in a gtk3 glarea?

Tags: python, gtk3, pyglet

I have seen a pygtk (gtk2) + pyglet [gist](https://gist.github.com/schlamar/4149031), but haven't found anything mentioning pyglet and gtk3.

Some pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's it basically identically the same? [GtkDrawingArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) is still the same pretty much?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you want to hear, but pyglet and Gtk both depend on their own main loop. So far nobody has figured out how to have two GUI programs with their own main loop get to work together nicely. So, you can't implement pyglet and Gtk in the same app.

At the bottom of the gist you linked, somebody posted that the gist only uses the GL context of pyglet. That is correct. Furthermore, this GL could also be imported from something like python(3)-opengl.

The code could be ported to Gtk3 but in my opinion the concept of merging pyglet and Gtk really isn't smart. If you want Gtk, use Gtk. If you want pyglet, use pyglet.

So, if you want to draw objects in Gtk, use either a [GtkDrawingArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) or a [GtkGLArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGLArea.html).

Comment: Pyglet seems to have a very popular API, which might justify people trying to use it. In the meantime I have tried wxpython + pyglet and it works quite well. Despite both having there own mainloops you are still able to make it work with a single loop: https://gist.github.com/Ryex/f8c9df05a65d311aa6ec

Comment: I am sorry to disagree, but you are not using the pyglet main loop. You are only using the OpenGL context of pyglet, and using the main loop of WxPython. This is what the Gtk2 + pyglet project was doing also. If this (whatever) works for you, then go for it.

Comment: I am also sorry, but I don't understand what you disagree with. I mentioned that "you are still able to make it work with a single loop". And this is nice because you can, for instance use the pyglet's Graphics interface: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/graphics.html

Comment: Actually, it's not that hard to implement your own [main loop](https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/blob/master/python/pyglet_base.py). Which I use all the time. You could implement a Gtk poller inside the same main function.